# How to parse this multi-dimensional array properly

Tags: php, arrays

I have tried everything I know and I have failed totally to parse this multi dimensional array so that I can get the "symbol" keys and corresponding values of "contractType" , but I can't seem to get it.

The array is generated here: https://fapi.binance.com/fapi/v1/exchangeInfo
So I am doing the following:

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $results = [];
    foreach ($data['symbols'] as $info) {
        $results[] = $info['symbol'];        
    }
    print_r($results);
```

I tried a foreach loop, for loop, tried various offsets eg. $data[0]['symbols']..
to $data[9]['symbols'] etc. but can't seem to get the correct array offset.

```
10000"}],"symbols":[{"symbol":"BTCUSDT","pair":"BTCUSDT","contractType":"PERPETUAL","deliveryDate
```

- I'm trying to loop through the "symbols" offset within this main array, and get 1. the "symbol" 2. its corresponding  "contractType"

Ty..

Comment: It's hard to answer this when you've only posted a partial of the array structure. Without knowing the full structure, we can only make unfounded guesses.

Comment: try to decode the json response you get from the CURL, `$data = json_decode($data);`. and now $data is an object that you can have accesses like `$data->symbols`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the CURL result is in JSON.

You got to convert it to an array before you can loop through it.

```
$data = json_decode($data, true);
```

Comment: Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given ...

Comment: @metokitt the `$data` in your original question is a string, this works with that code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to convert the JSON response into an array before you loop over it.

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $results = [];
    $data = json_decode($data);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($data->symbols as $info) {
        $results[$i]['symbol'] = $info->symbol;
        $results[$i]['contractType'] = $info->contractType;
        $i++;    
    }
    print_r($results);
```

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /data/www/.....

Comment: My bad, I posted the concept without testing. I have updated the answer for you now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Thankyou.. (didn't understand answer properly.)

```
    $url = 'https://fapi.binance.com/fapi/v1/exchangeInfo';
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $data = json_decode($data, true);

    $results = [];
    $symbols = $data['symbols'];
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($symbols as $info) {
        $results[$i]['symbol'] = $info['symbol'];
        $results[$i]['contractType'] = $info['contractType'];
        $i++;    
    }
    print_r($results);
```

Much appreciated, ty..